# Create single CSV from multiple csvs in a directory 1st CSV copy both columns subsequent csv only the 2nd column

Tags: php, html, csv, awk, sed

I am looking to create a single csv from many csvs in a directory.  I know that this has been covered many times, however I have a slight twist.  Things I am looking to do:

1. Find the largest file.
2. With the largest file - use that as the base.  The first column in the largest file will be the primary key that I need to merge the rest of the files.
3. Compare the each file in the directory to the primary key from the first CSV and add the second column of each csv to the largest one.

With that being said i am working with the following:

I found this link to take one column from one csv to another.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/553219/add-column-from-one-csv-to-another-csv-file

I can utilize something like this to add the column from one to another.

```
paste -d, file2 <(cut -d, -f3- file1)
```

The following PHP will get me the file list for a directory now trying to leverage PHP to combine / merge the csvs.

```
$dir= $Folder.'/Stats/Latency/'; // directory name 
$ar=scandir($dir); 
$box=$_POST['box'];  // Receive the file list from form

// Looping through the list of selected files ///
while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($box)) {
$path=$dir  ."/".$val;
$dest = $Folder."/Report/Latency/".$val;
if(copy($path, $dest)); //echo "Copy Complete file ";
echo "$val,";
}
echo "<hr>";
```

This is where i need the CSV merge below:
I am debating to utilize the shell exec commands but that seems very labor intensive.

```
$reportFiles = $Folder."/Report/Latency/";
foreach(glob($reportFiles."*.csv") as $file)
{
   shell_exec("touch "$reportFiles."latencyReport.csv");

}
```

As it relates to the data in the csv files:

CSV1:

```
date,vpool06
2016-03-28 12:00:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:01:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:02:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:03:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:04:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:05:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:06:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:07:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:08:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:09:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:10:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:11:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:12:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:13:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:14:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:15:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:16:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:17:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:18:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:19:00,0.000
```

CSV2:

```
date,vpool02
2016-03-28 12:00:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:01:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:02:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:04:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:05:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:06:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:07:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:08:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:09:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:10:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:11:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:12:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:13:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:14:00,0.000
```

CSV3:

```
date,vpool03
2016-03-28 12:00:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:01:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:02:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:04:00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:05:00,0.000
```

Merged CSV:

```
date,vpool06,vpool02,vpool03
2016-03-28 12:00:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:01:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:02:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:03:00,0.000,,0.000
2016-03-28 12:04:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:05:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:06:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:07:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:08:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:09:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:10:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:11:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:12:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:13:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:14:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:15:00,0.000,,
2016-03-28 12:16:00,0.000,,
2016-03-28 12:17:00,0.000,,
2016-03-28 12:18:00,0.000,,
2016-03-28 12:19:00,0.000,,
```

Ideally i don't care if there is a "null" value at this point because it just won't show up in the graph.  Meaning that the server was off at the time.

Need it to have null in the spaces where there is no data.
update: example.

```
date,vpool06,7NA_01,7NA_02,bd01,bd02,vpool01,vpool02,vpool03,vpool04,vpool07
2016-03-28 12:00:00,1.000,null,10.00,02.00,20.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:01:00,0.000,11.00,110.00,null,11.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:02:00,0.000,null,0.00,2.00,100,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.000
2016-03-28 12:03:00,0.000,0.00,0.00,02.00,10.00,0.00,0.000,0.00,0.00,0.000
```

Comment: `2016-03-28 12:03:00,0.000,,0.000` is not consistent with the input files

Comment: Define "largest file". Most rows, most columns, most bytes, something else? Also, clarify if you need a PHP solution or an AWK solution or something else.

Comment: Most Rows - never thought of that... great question - if i could do the most rows that would be even better.  PHP would be the best option - because i am creating a select script that moves the files into that directory - then after that it can combine the files and merge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea how you'd do that in PHP but with GNU awk for true 2D arrays and sorted "in" it'd be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1 { hdr[ARGIND][1]=$1; hdr[ARGIND][2]=$2; next }
{ arr[ARGIND][$1] = $2 }
END {
    for (idx in arr) {
        numRows = length(arr[idx])
        if (numRows > maxRows) {
            maxRows = numRows
            maxIdx  = idx
        }
    }

    printf "%s%s%s", hdr[maxIdx][1], OFS, hdr[maxIdx][2]
    for (idx=1; idx<=ARGIND; idx++) {
        if (idx != maxIdx) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, hdr[idx][2]
        }
    }
    print ""

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (tstamp in arr[maxIdx]) {
        printf "%s%s%s", tstamp, OFS, arr[maxIdx][tstamp]
        for (idx=1; idx<=ARGIND; idx++) {
            if (idx != maxIdx) {
                printf "%s%s", OFS, (tstamp in arr[idx] ? arr[idx][tstamp] : "null")
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk csv3 csv2 csv1
date,vpool06,vpool03,vpool02
2016-03-28 12:00:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:01:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:02:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:03:00,0.000,null,null
2016-03-28 12:04:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:05:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:06:00,0.000,null,0.000
2016-03-28 12:07:00,0.000,null,0.000
2016-03-28 12:08:00,0.000,null,0.000
2016-03-28 12:09:00,0.000,null,0.000
2016-03-28 12:10:00,0.000,null,0.000
2016-03-28 12:11:00,0.000,null,0.000
2016-03-28 12:12:00,0.000,null,0.000
2016-03-28 12:13:00,0.000,null,0.000
2016-03-28 12:14:00,0.000,null,0.000
2016-03-28 12:15:00,0.000,null,null
2016-03-28 12:16:00,0.000,null,null
2016-03-28 12:17:00,0.000,null,null
2016-03-28 12:18:00,0.000,null,null
2016-03-28 12:19:00,0.000,null,null
```

Comment: i tested this worked - however after testing it dygraphs require `null` value if there is no data in a column.  Example provided in the main question.  Is there a way to add null into the cells that donot have data?

Comment: Why would you add new sample output unrelated to your posted input instead of just fixing your original output? That would have been much simpler and clearer. Anyway, I've updated my answer to do what I THINK you now want.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==1{c++} {a[$1,c]=$2;keys[$1]}
                       END{for(k in keys) 
                            {printf "%s", k; 
                             for(i=1;i<=c;i++) 
                                 printf "%s", OFS (((k,i) in a)?a[k,i]:""); 
                             print ""}}' file{1,2,3} | 
 sort -t, -k1,1 | 
 tee >(sed '$d' > merged) >(tail -1 >> merged) 

$ cat merged

date,vpool06,vpool02,vpool03                                                                                          
2016-03-28 12:00:00,0.000,0.000,0.000                                                                                 
2016-03-28 12:01:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:02:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:03:00,0.000,,
2016-03-28 12:04:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:05:00,0.000,0.000,0.000
2016-03-28 12:06:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:07:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:08:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:09:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:10:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:11:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:12:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:13:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:14:00,0.000,0.000,
2016-03-28 12:15:00,0.000,,
2016-03-28 12:16:00,0.000,,
2016-03-28 12:17:00,0.000,,
2016-03-28 12:18:00,0.000,,
2016-03-28 12:19:00,0.000,,
```

Comment: what did we do before process-substitution  (`>(cmd ...)`) ? ;-) As always, an instructive, yet concise answer. Good luck to all.